# Working with large size branches of SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

We follow the practice of having new branch for developing new feature and again merge particular branch after completing development into trunk.

Now problem is that we have `400MB size of trunk` and every time when we do `code checkout of new feature branch` it `takes a lot time`. Is there any way to overcome this because unnecessarily it stops me waiting for code to be checkout from `remote server`. In fact, i have same code on my machine inside `trunk` but svn info points to trunk and needs to point to `new feature branch`. Any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svn help switch
switch (sw): Update the working copy to a different URL within the same repository.
usage: 1. switch URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]
       ...

  1. Update the working copy to mirror a new URL within the repository.
     This behavior is similar to 'svn update', and is the way to
     move a working copy to a branch or tag within the same repository.
     If specified, PEGREV determines in which revision the target is first
     looked up.
```